# How do I store user input into a list?

Tags: python

For example if I have a user input called `num`:

```
num = int(input('Enter numbers'))
```

I want to be able to store these numbers into a list to be manipulated.
How can I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: this would get a single number.

Comment: defined `L = []` then `for i in range(5): L.append(int(input('Enter numbers')))`

Comment: how the numbers are delimited?? like 1234 or 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 1):

The prompt "Enter numbers" suggests that the user will enter several numbers on the one line, so split the line and convert each number to an `int`. This list comprehension is a convenient way to do it:

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input('Enter numbers: ').split()]
```

The above is for Python 3. For Python 2, use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead:

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in raw_input('Enter numbers: ').split()]
```

In either case:

```
>>> numbers = [int(n) for n in raw_input('Enter numbers: ').split()]
Enter numbers: 1 2 3 4 5
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_numbers = raw_input("Enter numbers divided by spaces")

input_numbers_list = [int(n) for n in input_numbers.split()]

print input_numbers_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a single line by using functional programming construct of python called map,

python2

```
input_list = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

python3

```
input_list = map(int, input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
list_of_inputs = input("Write numbers: ").split() 
#.split() will split the inputted numbers and convert it into a list 
list_of_inputs= list(map(int , list_of_inputs))
#as the inputted numbers will be saved as a string. This code will convert the string into integers
```

output:

```
Write numbers: 43 5 78
>>> print (list_of_inputs)
[43, 5, 78]
```

i am using python 3.6